# Memory usage increases when reload the same file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Each time I load a npy file, the memory usage increases. The following mini-example illustrates this problem.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.randn(10000,10000)
np.save('tmp.npy',X)
```

Now, if the following line is executed several times, then each time the memory usage will increase

```
y=np.load('tmp.npy')
```

I found the exact similar problem with npz file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244397/memory-overflow-when-using-numpy-load-in-a-loop#), yet the solution is to use a function that is applicable to npy file. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise is flawed: memory usage does temporarily increase when loading the file, and may increase again the second time, and perhaps even the third, but eventually the garbage collector will run and the memory will be freed.

If you don't want to wait for nondeterministic time to reclaim the memory, you can explicitly force the garbage collector to run whenever need to reclaim memory:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

You can also explicitly delete the array after loading it, if you no longer need the data:

```
del y
```

But if you do neither of these things, and simply load the same data over and over forever, memory usage will not grow forever--at some point the garbage collector will run and the memory usage will shrink.  This happens automatically, and you usually do not need to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I was working on a script that each time loop over a group of files, loading them, then making some calculation, and so on. I found that after the first few iterations, the script was terminated with a memory error. I think that the automatic garbage collector is working may be slower than what my script needs.